# Spark DataFrame API does not yield the same result as Spark SQL version

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm trying to convert a SQL string to a Spark DataFrame API format. However, I get a different result when I use the DataFrame API. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? To be specific, I want to know why I'm getting different records. I don't mind the different layout.

**SQL code**

```
spark.sql("""SELECT delay, origin, destination,
              CASE
                  WHEN delay > 360 THEN 'Very Long Delays'
                  WHEN delay > 120 AND delay < 360 THEN  'Long Delays '
                  WHEN delay > 60 AND delay < 120 THEN  'Short Delays'
                  WHEN delay > 0 and delay < 60  THEN   'Tolerable Delays'
                  WHEN delay = 0 THEN 'No Delays'
                  ELSE 'No Delays'
               END AS Flight_Delays
               FROM us_delay_flights_tbl
               ORDER BY origin, delay DESC""").show(10, truncate=False)
```

**Spark DataFrame API code**

```
df.select("delay", "origin", "destination", 
          F.when(col("delay") > 360, "Very Long Delays")\
          .when((col("delay") > 120) & (col("delay") < 360), "Long Delays")\
          .when((col("delay") > 60) & (col("delay") < 120), "Short Delays")\
          .when((col("delay") > 0) & (col("delay") < 60), "Tolerable Delays")\
          .when(col("delay") == 0, "No Delays").otherwise("No Delays"))\
.orderBy("origin", "delay", ascending=False).show(10)
```

**The result I get from the SQL string (which I want)**

```
|delay|origin|destination|Flight_Delays|
+-----+------+-----------+-------------+
|333  |ABE   |ATL        |Long Delays  |
|305  |ABE   |ATL        |Long Delays  |
|275  |ABE   |ATL        |Long Delays  |
|257  |ABE   |ATL        |Long Delays  |
|247  |ABE   |ATL        |Long Delays  |
|247  |ABE   |DTW        |Long Delays  |
|219  |ABE   |ORD        |Long Delays  |
|211  |ABE   |ATL        |Long Delays  |
|197  |ABE   |DTW        |Long Delays  |
|192  |ABE   |ORD        |Long Delays  |
+-----+------+-----------+-------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

**The result I get from the DataFrame API (which is not what I want)**

```
|  475|   YUM|        PHX|Very Long Delays|
|  347|   YUM|        LAX|Long Delays|
|  333|   YUM|        LAX|Long Delays|
|  285|   YUM|        PHX|Long Delays|
|  267|   YUM|        LAX|Long Delays|
|  236|   YUM|        LAX|Long Delays|
|  231|   YUM|        LAX|Long Delays|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that in your `SQL query` you have mentioned `ORDER BY origin, delay DESC`
which means order your rows with `origin` in *ascending* order and `delay` with *descending* order.In the `DataFrame` API version of this, in which you set the `ascending` flag as `False`, which implies order by `origin` column in *descending* as well as `delay` column in *descending* manner.

if you want to have a sample result with DataFrame API same as your SQL query then you can it modify as follows:

```
orderBy(["origin", "delay"], ascending=[1, 0])
```

you can refer to this link to get a better idea : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=take#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.orderBy